# javascript createElement(),  style problem

Tags: javascript

today i wrote this function:

```
 function zoom(obj){
            var img = (!document.getElementById(obj))?false:document.getElementById(obj);
            var fullImage = (img.getAttribute("image") == null)?false:img.getAttribute("image");
            if(!fullImage || !img) { return false; }
            if(!document.getElementById("::img")) {
            var ob = "<div id='::img' style='position:absolute;top:300px;left:300px;width:200px;height:200px;-moz-border-radius:100px;border:1px solid #ddd;-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #fff;display:none;'></div>";
            document.write(ob);}
            img.onmousemove = function(e) {
            var x = Math.floor(((e.pageX-7) - (img.offsetLeft - 8)) * 100 / img.width);
            var y = Math.floor(((e.pageY-7) - (img.offsetTop - 8)) * 100 / img.height);
            x = (x>100)?100:(x<0)?0:x;
            y = (y>100)?100:(y<0)?0:y;
            var ob = document.getElementById("::img");
            ob.style.background = "url('" + fullImage + "') no-repeat";
            ob.style.display = 'block';
            ob.style.backgroundPosition = x + '% ' + y + '%';
            ob.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
            ob.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
            }
            img.onmouseout = function() { document.getElementById("::img").style.display='none'; }
        }
```

1. I tried to use createElement() and appendChild() functions instead of this :

   ```
    var ob = `""`;
               document.write(ob);
   ```

   but function does't work, how to make it to work with createElement().
2. is it possible to add all style with one line code with pure **JAVASCRIPT** :

```
ob.style.background = "url('" + fullImage + "') no-repeat";
                ob.style.display = 'block';
                ob.style.backgroundPosition = x + '% ' + y + '%';
                ob.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
                ob.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
```

**Preview: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SfphR/8/)**

Answer (score 151, accepted):

[Works fine:](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/SfphR/9/)

```
var obj = document.createElement('div');
obj.id = "::img";
obj.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;top:300px;left:300px;width:200px;height:200px;-moz-border-radius:100px;border:1px  solid #ddd;-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px  #fff;display:none;';

document.getElementById("divInsteadOfDocument.Write").appendChild(obj);
```

You can also see how to set the the CSS in one go (using `element.style.cssText`).

---

I suggest you use some more meaningful variable names and don't use the same name for different elements. It looks like you are using `obj` for different elements (overwriting the value in the function) and this can be confusing.

Comment: omg funny but i tried same thing about 30 mins ago and it didn't work (i think i missed something).. thats why i used document.write... thanks

Comment: This was exactly what I needed thanks for the info.

Comment: why cant we use `obj.className = 'some class'`

Comment: @PhaneendraCharyuluKanduri: You can do that too.

Answer (score 32):

```
yourElement.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red; font-size:2em;");
```

Or you could write the element as pure HTML and use `.innerHTML = [raw html code]`... that's very ugly though.

In answer to your first question, first you use `var myElement = createElement(...);`, then you do `document.body.appendChild(myElement);`.

Comment: This won't work in some versions of Internet Explorer. The safer solution is to use `yourElement.style.cssText`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `appendChild` function to append your new element to an existing element in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Others have given you the answer about appendChild.

Calling `document.write()` on a page that is not open (e.g. has finished loading) first calls `document.open()` which clears the entire content of the document (including the script calling document.write), so it's rarely a good idea to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page when I was trying to set the `backgroundImage` attribute of a div, but hadn't wrapped the `backgroundImage` value with `url()`. This worked fine:

```
for (var i=0; i<20; i++) {
  // add a wrapper around an image element
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.className = 'image-cell';

  // add the image element
  var img = document.createElement('div');
  img.className = 'image';
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150)';

  // add the image to its container; add both to the body
  wrapper.appendChild(img);
  document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
}
```