# How to get values from MySQL and print them into PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, identifier

I'm working on a chat application with HTML, jQuery, PHP and MySQL. My program looks like this: on the left you have users bar, where you can find all the users (the program also displays whether user is online or not, but this I can handle). When you click a user from the list, it generates a draggable container div that looks like this:

`<div class="container"><div class="head"></div><div id="conversation"></div></div>`

Specification: the "head" class is used just to display the partner's avatar and toggle the "conversation" div on click.

My problem:

I think I will load the conversation inside the "conversation" div using AJAX and JavaScript so it will refresh the div without refreshing the page. The user will have multiple user conversations opened at a time, so I need an idea about how to identify which conversation to load in each div. I'm stuck here.

Optional: I want the user to see when the partner has seen the message, but I think I can display "Seen at DATE." when the `conversation` is set to visible. If you have another suggestion, feel free to explain.

Every information is taken from a MySQL database.

My PHP display function looks like this:

```
<?php

include_once('connect.php');

$you = $SESSION['user'];
$takeconversation = "SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE sender='$partner' AND receiver='$you' OR sender='$you' AND receiver='$partner'";
$dotake = mysqlquery($takeconversation);
?>
```

So `$you` is the `$SESSION['user']`, but I need to add an identifier to give a value to `$partner`, so `$partner` would have a different value for every conversation div.

Comment: I can't figure out what your actual question is here, but you have a glaring SQL injection vulnerability. I suggest you read up on PDO and parameterized queries.

Comment: I know, I will recreate the selection code to prevent this. Let me explain: I have a SQL table with those fields: id - sender - receiver - message
when an user opens a window (div) from the friends list, it would take all the messages where sender is the user and receiver is the partner or sender is partner and receiver is user. But I need to do this in multiple windows at a time, so it would select the conversation with another friend in another div. Like the Facebook chat: you can chat multiple friends at a time.

Comment: The question is: how to identify the partner and display the conversation with that partner for every div opened?

Comment: u need to have the partner id by they time the user clicks on its name not when the new div opens

Comment: But I have a question. Let's say the user clicks on John and $partner takes the value "John", then he wants to talk with Andrew too and $partner takes the value "Andrew". Will the window with John still load messages?

Comment: Please edit your question and ask exactly what you want, Don't describe whole working or things that has no relevance with question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, The function is [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), not mysqlquery. Secondly, string comparison in mysql works better with the LIKE operator (at least, for me this seems to be the case).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you count the amount of conversations, create a `<div>` for each of those and append them to the main site. See [How can I create and style a div using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840326/how-can-i-create-and-style-a-div-using-javascript) Give meaningful names like `NUMBER_PARTNERNAME` either to `ID` or `name` of the div so you can later address it easily.

Comment: If you identify the partner by the div id/name then you should always verify that the user has permission to send to that specific partner, using mysql and php. (This depends on the application of course) Otherwise the user could just use dev tools or similar and change the id/name of the div.