# how to positioning the divs using the javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

i have a below code. i need to position the div elements.

```
<div id="outer" style="width:300px">
<canvas></canvas>
<div id="inner">
<div class="a"> val1 </div>
<div class="a"> val2 </div>
<div class="a"> val3 </div>
<div class="a">val4</div>
</div>
</div>
.a{
'overflow': 'hidden',
'text-overflow': 'ellipsis',
'white-space': 'nowrap'
}
```

I need to position the innerdiv around the canvas element. suppose if i give the position bottom the comes under the canvas element and should be horizontally center aligned. if i give the position right the inner div should be right of the canvas and it should be vertically center aligned.i am giving the attribute position to the script. i tried a lot in JavaScript through CSS. 
Suppose if no space in the outer div the inner div text need to shrink with ...(dots)..please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can set css property somthing like this

```
document.getElementById("id").style.porpertyName = "value" ;
```

Comment: thing i need is what are the css needed for the "outer" div,canvas element and "inner" div to get my requirement..

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "white";
div.innerHTML = "Hello";

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

[Refer This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840326/how-can-i-create-and-style-a-div-using-javascript/6840352#6840352)

Comment: yes i know how to add css properties. i just want what are all the css properties required to get my requirement...