# is there an alternative for building dropdown menu from json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, reactjs

recently a see a project for build form from json

https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form

I need to know if there is any way to do menu from json

[image]

i need to build a menu with simple procedures like this that actives with mouseenter and mouseleave

please help me

Comment: can u share what you had tried from that "recently a see a project"??

Comment: yes i forget of put the link , https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form

Comment: Certainly. The following steps will guide you towards the right Direction.

1) Construct a JSON with all the relevant info you need about your Menu (Titles of Menu Items , probably Colors , Widths , Events , etc) 
2) Parse your JSON with JSON.parse();
3) Create a <ul></ul> element and give it an ID
4) Loop through your new JSON Object properites and start adding <li></li> elements to your <ul>

Comment: This could help: http://www.jqwidgets.com/building-menu-from-json/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create your own interface and controller. I will try to give a idea . Create function for adding html div tags from code .

Create json like this or load from file (same staff) - (use httprequest if you wanna json from file or remote server) :

//html code

```
<div id="menuHolder" style="width:200px;height:60px" ></div>

// generic from code example
var MENU_DATA = {
"DisplayText" : "Select drop menu" , 
 items : [ "select1" , "select2" , ... , "selectn"]

};

function refreshMenu(){
// clear holder 
document.getElementById("menuHolder").innerHTML = "";
for (var x=0;x<MENU_DATA.items.length;x++) {
  // i use simple method for creating divs but this is better 
  // look at [Answer for nice creating dom elements][1]
  document.getElementById("menuHolder").innerHTML += "<div id='id_"+x+"' onclick='CLICK_METHOD("+x+")' > "+ MENU_DATA.items[x] +" </div>";

}
}


  function CLICK_METHOD (IndexOfClicedItem) {

          if (IndexOfClicedItem == 1) {

                 CALL_EVENT_FOR_SELECT1() 

            }
   }

// For working like drop menu you will need to add click event on holder .

  // Create var for status OPENED / CLOSED menu
  // On open make height for example 500px on close back to 60px 
  // Need css for overflow hidden for holder div ...
```

I hope this all is 2h of work ...
  Call on the end refreshMenu() , also you can edit it any time just call refreshMenu() to make new html look .

Style of dinamic added divs also need style setup , like width: 100% 
  Try absolute / relative . Use one Special Select from list , they will append text from clicked drop item .

[Answer for nice way of creating dom elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840326/how-can-i-create-and-style-a-div-using-javascript)

Comment: very thank you for all

Comment: please redefine question like : What procedures need to build dropMenu control with native js ... question is in onHold

Comment: i dont understand well , that you refer with procedures , i need only create a simple menu like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0I10.jpg

Comment: If you ask me question is ok .