# How to create a div element on click? And the div to appper where I click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a div on click using javascript .All the code I found is using an already created div in the body .But I want the div to be created only on click and as many times the users wants.

```
document.body.onclick = function () {
    var i;
    i = document.createElement('div');
    i.style.height = "10px";
    i.style.width = "10px";
    i.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.body.appendChild(i);
}
```

Comment: This already works. Your issue is probably that the body is too short. Adding this css makes the code work: `html,body{height:100%;}`

Comment: Where did you define this function? Need context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create and style a div using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840326/how-can-i-create-and-style-a-div-using-javascript)

Comment: @TirthaR in that question there already is a div "main " in the html body . I need to create a div on click and where the mouse is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `document.body.onclick` function will not work.This is due to there is ***no content in the body*** as well as ***no area set for body*** in default.

By doing some [**css**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51233282/1081909) changes it can work however 
you can achieve this using `window.onclick event` as simplest way.

To create the `div` on mouse click location you need to set the div's position to `absolute`, and set its `left` and `top` to the mouse position by getting `event.clientX` and `event.clientY`

```js
window.onclick = function (e) {
  var i;
  i = document.createElement('div');
  i.style.height = "10px";
  i.style.width = "10px";
  i.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  i.style.position = "absolute";
  i.style.left = e.clientX+'px';
  i.style.top = e.clientY+'px';
  document.body.appendChild(i);

}
```

Comment: But ... I want it to create the divs where I click .

Comment: @Andrada You need to set the div's position to `absolute`, and set its `left` and `top` to the mouse position.

Comment: @Andrada- I updated my answer based on your requirement.

Comment: @NullPointer thank you . It would have taken me ages to figure that one out.

Comment: Now the important part of the description resembles to my answer.........

Answer (score 2):

As there is no content in the body and by default there is no area set for `body`, you are not able to click on the `body`. Hence your function is not being called at all. Either you set the some area for body or use `window.onclick`:

```js
window.onclick = function (e) {
  var i, left = e.clientX, top = e.clientY;
  i = document.createElement('div');
  i.style.left = left+ "px";
  i.style.top = top+ "px";
  i.style.position = "absolute";
  i.style.height = "10px";
  i.style.width = "10px";
  i.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.body.appendChild(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you . But i want it to create the divs where I click .

Comment: @Andrada Why doesn't it say that in the question?

Comment: @Andrada, you have to set some additional styles to achieve that. I have updated my answer....please check.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your css. The body is at a height of `0px` when it doesn't have any initial content, so this means with what you have you need to click on that zero pixel which is probably impossible. By setting the height of the body (in the css) we can click on it.

```js
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
  //console.log(e)
  let i = document.createElement('div');
  i.style.height = "10px";
  i.style.width = "10px";
  i.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  i.style.position = 'absolute';
  i.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
  i.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
  document.body.appendChild(i);
}
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
```