# Html injection into javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

first of all i should say that it's my first day of learning java script.

Basically i'm trying to create chrome extention which will add dummy button after search bar button in "google.com".

So far i've written this code:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("btnK");
if (typeof x[0] === 'undefined' || x[0] === null) {

} else {
    parent = x[0].parentElement;
    button = document.createElement("button");
    parent.appendChild(button);
}
```

As you can see i'm getting google's search button, then getting parent of it and add button as last to it. 
The issue here is that after i'm creating this button it can't be modified in any way.

As i understand i can't change style or text of newly created element, only elements that was already defined when form was loading. So, knowing this information i want to ask(my question is below)

***Question:*** Is there any way to insert button, created in html code into my script?

***Note:*** I understand it might be easy and trivial question, and i'm sorry that i couldn't find clear and right answer just by googling, so far i'm kind of confused with javascript

***Edit:*** After comment i need to clearify one thing. **I can't use any of code to the button after `createElement`, it has no effect, so basically i need to create it with style already deined somehow**

***Edits:*** Thanks all for the suggestion in comments, here what i've tried so far:

**1st approach:**

As was suggested, i just straight copy button "search", change it a bit and readded to parent. I hoped to see three buttons now, but it's just redrawed search button in new position, here's the code:

```
x[0].value = "test"
parent.appendChild(x[0]);
```

**2nd approach:**

Create button, then get it and change, also not working, here's the code:

```
button.id = "dummyId"
parent.appendChild(button);
var styledButton = document.getElementById("dummyId");
styledButton.value = "test";
```

It changed the value if i'm looking at this button in "inspect element", but visually it's empty

**Guys, sorry, it was my stupidity. It just that `value` field doesn't change text !!! And also i needed to create input, not value**

So, final soultion:

```
    input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "submit"
    input.value = "test"
    parent.appendChild(input);
```

Sorry again

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/5927054/4997836

Comment: @NijrajGelanim Hi, thanks for the reply, the issue here, as i already mentioned in my question, is that i can't modify element in any way after creating, even button.value = "text" isn't working, so i need to create with style defined already

Comment: Give a unique id to the element and just `getElementById` and modify style when you want it to change?

Comment: **button.style.color** and many other styles options.. And if you want to insert already existing button from html... **parent.appendChild(document.getElementbyId('myButtonId'));**

Comment: @damitj07, please see edits

Comment: @NijrajGelani, please see edits

Comment: Do not use numeric IDs - Feel free to delete the question if you can

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, you're totally right, i just wanted to make fast test, i don't do such things in real code

Comment: Never do it. Not even in tests. You will be surprised how many shortcuts end up in production code and bites your butt later. Use "x" if you need shortcuts. PS: The personal pronoun "I" is a capital letter

Answer (score 1):

When you create the button, you can add, add text, classes, event listeners etc.

```
button = document.createElement("button");
button.id = 'my-new-button';
button.textContent = 'Click me';
button.classList.add('my-button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('clickie');
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ubmb6p3f/1/