# How to print and capitalize user input?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a prompt that's supposed to capitalize user input and print it into the HTML.
But it won't capitalize the input, what am I doing wrong?

```js
var name = prompt("What's your name?");
var fullname = name;

function capitalize() {
    fullname.style.textTransform = "capitalize";
}
document.write(fullname);
```

Comment: You're trying to invoke the `style` property of a variable? It won't work unless that variable points to an HTML element or is an object with a property named `style`. You might be getting an exception on your browser console.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927012/javascript-createelement-style-problem

Answer (score 3):

Aside from  he fact that you never call your `capitalize` method, `fullname` is just a string. `style.textTransform` is how you might set the `style` properties of an HTML element.

```js
var name = prompt("What's your name?");
var elem = document.querySelector('#output');
elem.style.textTransform = "capitalize";
elem.innerText = name;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not `capitalize`, it's `uppercase`.

```js
var name = prompt("What's your name?");
var elem = document.querySelector('#output');
elem.style.textTransform = "uppercase";
elem.innerText = name;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```